# Replacing Sympy indexed symbols with numeric values

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy expression I want to put numerical values in after differentiating it. The variables I want to replace are all the x[i], y[i] and R_abs[i] in the last expression and are numpy arrays a la

```
rx=np.array([-0.357, -0.742, -1.078,  0.206])
```

But trying subs or replace either doesn't do anything or raises the error that Symbols dont allow indexation for for example e1.subs(x[1],rx[0]). I pretty much went through every iteration I could think of to no avail.

```
import sympy as sp
    
r0,ge_x,ge_y,bx,by = sp.symbols('r0,ge_x,ge_y,bx,by', real=True) #Main symbols

i,x,y,R_abs = sp.symbols('i,x,y,R_abs', real=True) #Helper symbols
n=4

s2=sp.Sum((bx+r0*sp.Indexed('x',i)/sp.Indexed('R_abs',i)+ge_x*sp.Indexed('x',i)+ge_y*sp.Indexed('y',i)-sp.Indexed('x',i))**2+(by+r0*sp.Indexed('y',i)/sp.Indexed('R_abs',i)-ge_x*sp.Indexed('y',i)+ge_y*sp.Indexed('x',i)-sp.Indexed('y',i))**2,(i,1,n))

e1=sp.Eq(sp.diff(s2,bx).doit(),0)
```

With e1 then being

```
Eq(8*bx + 2*ge_x*x[1] + 2*ge_x*x[2] + 2*ge_x*x[3] + 2*ge_x*x[4] + 2*ge_y*y[1] + 2*ge_y*y[2] + 2*ge_y*y[3] + 2*ge_y*y[4] + 2*r0*x[4]/R_abs[4] + 2*r0*x[3]/R_abs[3] + 2*r0*x[2]/R_abs[2] + 2*r0*x[1]/R_abs[1] - 2*x[1] - 2*x[2] - 2*x[3] - 2*x[4], 0)
```

In here I would like to replace all the x, y, and R_abs with their numerical values.

Comment: As a general rule, using `sympy` and `numpy` together is an advanced topic.  While you can use `sympy.lambdify` to create a function that works with numpy arrays, I suspect in this case sticking with `sympy` will be easier.

Comment: I need to solve a system of equations made up by derivatives of s2 to figure out ge_x&y, bx&y, r0. I'd like to make the work easier for the computer by putting in the numerical values for known parameters.

Now I know marrying sympy and numpy is not something you want to do, but than again I'm only using numpy as storage at the moment.

Comment: For 1d storage, a list is just as good, if not better than an array.  Especially if you are just accessing elements by index (or other wise iterating).

Comment: Ideally I dont want to access them item by item. This is mainly caused by sympy not playing nice, the numpy array is a leftover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always struggled with indexing in SymPy. Turns out, making `Function` instances are way easier than indexing instances of `Symbol`. It also makes notation simpler.

Also note that by using strings in your expression, I think SymPy makes its own symbols with those same string names but they can't be accessed with yours since your symbols are different. At least that's what happens sometimes to me.

Here is a working sample:

```py
import sympy as sp

r0, ge_x, ge_y, bx, by = sp.symbols("r0 ge_x ge_y bx by", real=True)  # main symbols

# define functions that will take the role of indexed symbols
x = sp.Function("x")
y = sp.Function("y")
R_abs = sp.Function("R_abs")
i = sp.Symbol("i", positive=True, integer=True)
n = 4

s2 = sp.Sum((bx + r0 * x(i) / R_abs(i) + ge_x * x(i) + ge_y * y(i) - x(i)) ** 2 +
            (by + r0 * y(i) / R_abs(i) - ge_x * y(i) + ge_y * x(i) - y(i)) ** 2, (i, 1, n))

s2_prime = sp.diff(s2, bx).doit().simplify()
print(s2_prime)

# whatever lists you want. Can even be an instance of `np.ndarray`
# note that you summed from 1 to n so the 0th element will not be used
x_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y_array = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
R_abs_array = [-10, 10, 5, 4, 3]

# define a function to access these array elements
x_function = lambda index: x_array[index]
y_function = lambda index: y_array[index]
R_abs_function = lambda index: R_abs_array[index]

# no idea why subs does not work and you MUST keep the same name for the variable.
# you can't have for example `evaluated_s2_prime = ...`.
# Probably something to do with forcing sp to remove references to `x`?
s2_prime = s2_prime.replace(x, x_function).replace(y, y_function).replace(R_abs, R_abs_function)
print(s2_prime)
```

Producing:

```
8*bx + 2*ge_x*x(1) + 2*ge_x*x(2) + 2*ge_x*x(3) + 2*ge_x*x(4) + 2*ge_y*y(1) + 2*ge_y*y(2) + 2*ge_y*y(3) + 2*ge_y*y(4) + 2*r0*x(4)/R_abs(4) + 2*r0*x(3)/R_abs(3) + 2*r0*x(2)/R_abs(2) + 2*r0*x(1)/R_abs(1) - 2*x(1) - 2*x(2) - 2*x(3) - 2*x(4)
8*bx + 20*ge_x + 12*ge_y + 31*r0/6 - 20
```

Comment: That seems to work, now to integrate it into my main program. 2 points to add.

1)  If I understand correctly replace is just a stupid Search&Replace operation with no idea what the math behind the expression is, correct?

2) Your arrays are 5 items long, the sum runs 1 to 4, so you are not using the first item. I fixed that by changing x_array[index] to x_array[index-1], etc

Comment: @Michkov 1) I think you are correct. It's almost like the `replace` for strings. 2) You could do that or you could keep the lambda functions the same and have the expression sum from `0` to `n-1` instead. It feels more natural, imo, to have everything starting from index 0 in order to keep things consistent.